# How to add each list entry as an entry to a json file in Python?

Tags: python, json, list, txt

I have the following list printed iteratively:

```
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/activate.ps1
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/f2py3
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/activate.fish
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/activate.csh
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/f2py
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/python3
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/pip
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/python3.9
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/activate_this.py
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/wheel3
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/python
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/wheel-3.9
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/pip-3.9
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/pip3.9
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/wheel
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/activate
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/pyvenv.cfg
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/log.json
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/main.py
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/hello_world.dat
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/b.exe
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/world_builder.spec
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/.idea/inspectionProfiles/Project_Default.xml
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/.idea/inspectionProfiles/profiles_settings.xml
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/.idea/.gitignore
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/.idea/modules.xml
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/.idea/file-tagging.iml
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/.idea/misc.xml
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/.idea/workspace.xml
/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/content-log.txt
```

I am trying to save these files to a JSON entry like this:

```
data_entry = {"path": "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/.idea/workspace.xml", "tags": []},
```

Every entry will have a `tags` object, which will be an empty list. This is because a single path could have many associated tags.

My goal is to initialize `logs.json` with every single element in the path lists each with a tag object containing an empty list. Then I want to be able to access this list.

The following is my attempt at populating `path` with every entry in the list but it didn't work:

```
import json

data_entry = {"path": "", "tags": []},

with open('log.json', 'w+') as read_file:
    for i in data_list:
        print(i)
        json.dump(i,read_file, indent=1)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 path_list = []

for i in data_list.splitlines():
    data_entry = {"path": i, "tags": []}
    path_list.append(data_entry)


with open('log.json', 'w+') as read_file:
    json.dump(path_list, read_file, indent=1)
```

output log.json

```
 [
 {
  "path": "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/activate.ps1",
  "tags": []
 },
 {
  "path": "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/f2py3",
  "tags": []
 },
 {
  "path": "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/activate.fish",
  "tags": []
 },
 {
  "path": "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/activate.csh",
  "tags": []
 }...]
```

or you can go with

```
{
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/activate.ps1": tags[],
    "/home/onur/PycharmProjects/file-tagging/venv/bin/f2py3": tags[],
    ...
}
```